# Error during WebSocket Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to get a websockets connection going, and I keep getting the following error: 
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=w6H2vNXXbYIOhwPQAAAA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

My code is very straightforward  - on the client side I am calling `this.socket = io();` and on the server side I am doing the below. I have noticed several related posts on this topic, and have tried a ton of variations, but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance :)

```
const app = require("http").createServer(handler);
const io = require("socket.io")(app);

app.listen(3000);

class Sockets {
  constructor() {
    this.humanPlayers = [];
    this.socket = io.listen(app);
    this.setEventHandlers();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for connections to the socket and then you can create a new `Sockets` instance after having received one from Socket.io. Then you can store the socket received from Socket.io to your new `Sockets` `socket` property.

```
const app = require("http").createServer(handler);
const io = require("socket.io")(app);   

class Sockets {
  constructor(socket) {
    this.humanPlayers = [];
    this.socket = socket;
    this.setEventHandlers();
  }
}

app.listen(3000);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  let connectedSocket = new Sockets(socket);
});
```